# Capturing Date Regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have two different file names:

```
"Profile sep 3 2015.txt"

"Profile mar 5 2014 inactive.txt"
```

What I need is a regex that captures the date `MMM dd yyyy` part of the file name.

Previously, I had a regex that would capture it like so:

```
"^Profile (.*).txt$"
```

But that doesn't account for the inactive files, as it would just be captured with the dates. How should I approach this?

Comment: You accepted a wrong regex actually, please reconsider accepting the answer that yields the most accurate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below pattern would help as a quick fix and we can enhance it covering other validations.

```
\s+([jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec]{3}\s*[0-3]?[0-9]\s*\d{4})/ig
```

This pattern covers:

- Months(mmm) should have a consistent length of 3 and case insensitive
- Day should be in the NN format
- Year should be in NNNN format
- Space between Month/Day/Year is optional

Attached screenshot is for reference and more examples can be tested at - http://regexr.com/

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your regex is incorrect since it matches [`" c|t391234"`](https://regex101.com/r/de5Xgq/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Its not good practice here to make such generalized statement "incorrect" when it is covering most use cases, but instead it needs to be enhanced as I clearly mentioned in my answer, so that it helps users when they try it rather than just ignoring everything based on such statements.

Comment: No, it is wrong because " |||02016" does not look like a date, and that is what [your regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/de5Xgq/2).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\s+\d{4}\b
```

Use with a *case-insensitive flag* (i.e. `/PATTERN_ABOVE/i` or add a `(?i)` before the first `\b`). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y3enrM/4). It will match space separated 3-letter month, 1 or 2 digit day and 4-digit year.

**Details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)` - a month
- `\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` - 1 or 2 day digits

  - `0?[1-9]`  - optional zero and a digit from 1-9 range
  - `|` - or
  - `[12][0-9]` - a number from `10` to `29`
  - `|`  - or
  - `3[01]` - `30` or `31`
- `\s+` - see above
- `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

Comment: The month's expression([a-zA-Z]{3}) supposed to work for only valid month's names(Jan, Feb etc), but not for every other strings that has length 3 (ex: mno, xyz are not valid)

Comment: @VeereshDevireddy: Now, my regex is working as you say.

Answer (score 1):

### POSIX Character Classes with Range Modifiers

You don't provide a specific language, so while there may be other ways to do this, a rather portable way would be using POSIX character classes with range modifiers. For example:

> ^Profile[[:space:]]+([[:alpha:]]{3}[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]{1,2}[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]{4})

For an explanation, here's an example using the extended syntax in Ruby:

```
str     = "Profile mar 5 2014 inactive.txt"
pattern =
  /                    # start regular expression literal
    ^Profile           # anchor to "Profile" at start of line
    [[:space:]]+       # one or more space\/tab characters
    (                  # start capture
      [[:alpha:]]{3}   # three alphabetical characters
      [[:space:]]+     # one or more space\/tab characters
      [[:digit:]]{1,2} # one or two digits
      [[:space:]]+     # one or more space\/tab characters
      [[:digit:]]{4}   # exactly four digits
    )                  # end capture
  /x                   # close literal; set the Regexp::EXTENDED flag
str.match pattern; $1
#=> "mar 5 2014"
```